# Conversion date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with date in SQL server management studio. A column contains 2 type of date, for example: '20/06/2020' and '2021-03-25'.
The column have as data_type varchar(10) and I must convert in date. I have used this comand:

```
select cast(column_name as date) column_name
        from dataset
```

ERROR:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How to can I resolve it?

Comment: you have to fix your data

Comment: and schema. Columns that store dates should **never** have been created as varchar in the first place.

Comment: what is your current `dateformat` setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `try_convert()` and `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(try_convert(date, col),       -- flexible, handles many formats
                try_convert(date, col, 103)   -- handles dd/mm/yyyy
               )
```

Note:  You may have other formats that this doesn't handle, so this might still return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the content and convert accordingly:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_name LIKE '%/%'
            THEN CONVERT(DATE, column_name, 103)
            ELSE CONVERT(DATE, column_name, 120)
       END AS ConvertedDate
FROM DATASET
```

For available date format values, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90)).

Comment: Solid approach especially if the DMY formats include the / .  However, I would use try_convert() to avoid throwing an error.  Being strings, there can be virtually anything in the cell   +1